# How does the assignment operator work here?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

```
int main()
{
  
  int y = 0;
  
  if(y = 1)
    cout<<"true"<<endl;

  else
    cout<<"false"<<endl;    
}
```

Output : true

How assignment operator work here? I am unable to understand the logic!

Comment: What has this question to do with bitmanipulation?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and the compiler would have pointed out in your valid code where you've made a mistake.